# Ibm notes maximum limit

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

At this link:
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTWP_8.5.3/com.ibm.notes85.client.doc/fram_limits_of_notes_r.html

I also see this :

Levels of responses in a hierarchical view; number of documents at each level

31 levels; 300,000 documents

Can someone explain what a hierarchical view is and what a level in this context means?

Are there also maybe any other 'database' limits with IBM Notes in which I need to pay my attention to. The reason for this is that there is an ERP application built in IBM Notes and I want to check if there are any database limit which I need to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A form in Notes can be designated as either a main document, a response document, or a response-to-response document. (The second type, a response document, is not used all that often because a response-to-response form can also be used to create a response to a main document.) For the latter two cases, any document created using that form will contain a special item, called "$Ref", that contains a pointer to a parent document. A hierarchical view is a view with a property labeled "Show response documents in a hierarhy" which tells the indexer to keep track of the relationships between parent and child documents in the collection defined by the view's selection formula, and to display the child documents in an indented hierarchy. In addition to the property, the view must also have a column that is marked with a "Show responses only" property. A main document can have children, and child documents can have children, and those child documents can have children for as many levels as you want - but the view will stop displaying them after 31 levels of indentation.

See [here](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/5d07ce46e254f88f85256c54004b783b?OpenDocument).